# Load Dcl inside Vlx (AutoLisp)

Tags: compilation, autolisp

I've create my entire aplication in autolisp, alright its time to compile and protect my code......., in the autolisp, to use DCL's you only need to load them, using :

```
(setq sample (load_dialog "C:/Users/my-user/Desktop/my-dcl.DCL"))

 (if (not (new_dialog "my-dialog" sample))
 (exit )
 )
```

or some equivalent code, but i know that it's possible to compile DCL's in the same vlx that you compile the lisp files. But how cold we load this DCL inside the vlx?, how to reference and load it?

Comment: DCL refers to the description language and interpreter within AutoCAD (Dialog Control Language) but also to the command line interpreter of OpenVMS (DIGITAL Command Language). On stackoverflow the tag DCL is currently associated with the latter; so please remove the DCL tag.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Use a relative reference in your code: `(setq sample (load_dialog "my-dcl.DCL"))`.

Step 2: Place the DCL in the same folder as the LISP file so the relative reference will work correctly.

Step 3: Use the Visual LISP IDE in AutoCAD to bundle the package together. Here's a tutorial: http://www.afralisp.net/visual-lisp/tutorials/compiling-part-2.php. I think Page 2 is what you want, but go back to Page 1 for more info if you have any trouble.

Good luck!